Factory reset in settings doesn't work, "Erase everything" button has no action
I am trying to do factory reset in settings on my Smartphone - Yotaphone 3+ with YetiOS based on Android 8.1, API level 27.
I enter the Settings -> System -> Reset options -> Erase all data (factory reset) -> Reset phone -> Erase everything
But no matter how many times I click this button "Erase everything" nothing happens. Button has no action.
Can this problem be fixed? Are there workarounds? Is this a bug?
This problem probably started after I flashed TWRP recovery, which works fine, instead of original recovery. Can this have an impact on the possibility of doing a factory reset in Android settings?
I attached several screenshots about this problem.



Thanks

What phone model and manufacturer do you try to reset? Normally phones can be directly factory reset via their recovery ROM by certain model specific key combinations (e.g. Volume down + power). In the end the UI button you have posted should erase the local accounts and the boot into recovery where automatically the factory reset is executed.

Thanks for the reply. I edited the post. The phone is Yotaphone 3+ with YetiOS based on Android 8.1. This problem probably started after I flashed TWRP recovery, which works fine, instead of original recovery. Can this have an impact on the possibility to do factory reset in Android settings?

TWRP can have an impact. But usually the phone should at least reboot when you press the "ERASE EVERYTHING" button. I would check that you have removed Google account from your device (or better all accounts) to be sure not running into factory reset protection. Then start into TWRP and Wipe "data" or "user data" partition.

Ok, I rebooted into TWRP (version 3.2.3-0). I did all options that I could find. Swipe to Factory Reset option. Did Advanced Wipe option, selected all: Dalvik/ART Cache, System, Data, Internal Storage, cache. Also did Format Data, which I believe might be used to wipe userdata, but I might be wrong. But unfortunately, after doing all that and choosing to reboot normally into Android OS the phone doesn't boot anymore :) Stuck on android logo (no worries I have many backups). adb devices returns nothing, fastboot devices returns ID so I guess phone is in bootloader/fastboot mode constantly

Well you have erased "System" which means you have erased Android OS. A phone without OS can't boot. Therefore I said erase "user" or "user data" only.

ahh, right, I reflashed system image again from backup and reinstalled Android from scratch. Also I removed all accounts (including google accounts) in Settings -> Users & accounts. But unfortunately "Erase everything" button for factory reset still doesn't work. Nothing happens after pressing it. I wonder if this is a bug or if this can be fixed somehow.

There's a few posts thread on XDA Forums (1, 2) mentioning doing factory reset successfully, though it's unclear if it's from Settings or Recovery. But it's also unclear why you still want to do this if you have wiped the data partition, since it's practically the same as factory reset? (the question is still valid though, I'm just curious)

Thanks for the provided links to interesting topics on XDA. I was just curious about this factory reset option in Android settings, in case when I sell this smartphone later to some person who might not know how to use TWRP
